# No error when underscore used between prefix and number

Tags: java, octal

The following code :

```
int i = 0_10;
System.out.println(i);
```

produces the output:

> 8

In the [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html), it is written that we *cannot put underscores
at the beginning of a number* as in the example `int x5 = 0x_52;`, which produces the error `illegal underscore`.

However, in this code, `0` is the prefix for octal numbers, as we can see that the output is `8`. But the error is not produced.

- The value of `i` is **8**, which means that `0_10` is an octal number, and `0` is the prefix.
- But `0_10` does not produce the **illegal underscore** error, which implies that `0` is not the prefix, but a part of the number.

Why does it not produce the error? Does java treat it *partially* as octal, and *partially* not?

Comment: According to [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/underscores-literals.html): "You can place underscores only between digits;" so `0_10` is legit

Comment: [They (Oracle Docs)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/underscores-literals.html) even have it as an explicit example: `int x9 = 0_52;             // OK (octal literal)`

Comment: From Hulk's link: *"In Java SE 7 and later, any number of underscore characters (_) can appear anywhere between digits in a numerical literal..."* Wow, I thought it was from much earlier than that.

Comment: there should be a compiler flag that bars all octal literals. (IntelliJ by default warns it)

Comment: hmm... have you ever used octal format? have you seen any code using it? I have never ever.

Comment: on the other hand, the new binary form is pretty sweet - `0b0101_0101`

Comment: @bayou.io Actually you are right. I don't see anyone using octal. But, I never knew about binary.... Is it available in java 7? Also, do we need to use `0b` two times, as you have done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the [JLS says](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.1):

> Underscores are allowed as separators **between digits** that denote the integer.

*(My emphasis)* The underscore in `0x_52` is not *between digits*.

Yes, it's a bit odd that the indicator that a number is in octal is just that it starts with a `0` (not followed by an `x`). And it's caused No End Of Confusion, but it (the `0`) *is* a digit, and so `0_10` fits the JLS rules.

It does go on to be explicit about it:

> In a hexadecimal or binary literal, the integer is only denoted by the digits after the 0x or 0b characters and before any type suffix. Therefore, underscores may not appear immediately after 0x or 0b, or after the last digit in the numeral.
>
> In a decimal or octal literal, the integer is denoted by all the digits in the literal before any type suffix.

Note the distinction. *(For clarity: By "type suffix" they're talking about the `l`/`L` for "long",  `f`/`F` for "float", etc.)*

> Does java treat it partially as octal, and partially not?

It doesn't. The `0` is part of the number, and also an indicator the number is in octal. It's a bizarre notational idea from C in the 1970s that got inherited by Java when Gosling was designing it to use a syntax similar to C's in the 1990s.

It's worth noting that this bizarre notation has caused enough trouble that when they *finally* officially added octal to JavaScript (a different language also using a similar syntax), they used `0o` as the prefix instead. (Prior to the 2015 spec, there was no official octal form in JavaScript, although note was made in the 2009 spec that some implementations had done the C thing. As of the 2009 spec they aren't allowed to in strict mode, and the 2015 spec introduced `0o`. [In the 2015 spec, they also made the old "legacy" form *required* in browsers [only] in loose mode, for compatibility reasons.])